# Switching from DELETE and INSERT to UPDATE and is it faster

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public boolean saveHighScore(Client c) throws SQLException {
    long totallvlexp = (long) (c.playerXP[0]) + (c.playerXP[1]) + (c.playerXP[2]) + (c.playerXP[3]) + (c.playerXP[4]) + (c.playerXP[5]) + (c.playerXP[6]) + (c.playerXP[7]) + (c.playerXP[8]) + (c.playerXP[9]) + (c.playerXP[10]) + (c.playerXP[11]) + (c.playerXP[12]) + (c.playerXP[13]) + (c.playerXP[14]) + (c.playerXP[15]) + (c.playerXP[16]) + (c.playerXP[17]) + (c.playerXP[18]) + (c.playerXP[19]) + (c.playerXP[20]); 
    int totallevell = (int) (c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[0]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[1]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[2]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[3]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[4]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[5]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[6]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[7]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[8]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[9]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[10]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[11]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[12]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[13]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[14]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[15]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[16]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[17]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[18]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[19]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[20]));
    String delQuery1 = "DELETE FROM `skills` WHERE playerName = '"+c.playerName+"';";
    String delQuery2 = "DELETE FROM `skillsoverall` WHERE playerName = '"+c.playerName+"';";
    String delQuery3 = "DELETE FROM `playerrights` WHERE playerName = '"+c.playerName+"';";
    String insQuery1 = "INSERT INTO `skills` (`playerName`,`Attacklvl`,`Attackxp`,`Defencelvl`,`Defencexp`,`Strengthlvl`,`Strengthxp`,`Hitpointslvl`,`Hitpointsxp`,`Rangelvl`,`Rangexp`,`Prayerlvl`,`Prayerxp`,`Magiclvl`,`Magicxp`,`Cookinglvl`,`Cookingxp`,`Woodcuttinglvl`,`Woodcuttingxp`,`Fletchinglvl`,`Fletchingxp`,`Fishinglvl`,`Fishingxp`,`Firemakinglvl`,`Firemakingxp`,`Craftinglvl`,`Craftingxp`,`Smithinglvl`,`Smithingxp`,`Mininglvl`,`Miningxp`,`Herblorelvl`,`Herblorexp`,`Agilitylvl`,`Agilityxp`,`Thievinglvl`,`Thievingxp`,`Slayerlvl`,`Slayerxp`,`Farminglvl`,`Farmingxp`,`Runecraftlvl`,`Runecraftxp`) VALUES ('"+c.playerName+"',"+c.playerLevel[0]+","+c.playerXP[0]+","+c.playerLevel[1]+","+c.playerXP[1]+","+c.playerLevel[2]+","+c.playerXP[2]+","+c.playerLevel[3]+","+c.playerXP[3]+","+c.playerLevel[4]+","+c.playerXP[4]+","+c.playerLevel[5]+","+c.playerXP[5]+","+c.playerLevel[6]+","+c.playerXP[6]+","+c.playerLevel[7]+","+c.playerXP[7]+","+c.playerLevel[8]+","+c.playerXP[8]+","+c.playerLevel[9]+","+c.playerXP[9]+","+c.playerLevel[10]+","+c.playerXP[10]+","+c.playerLevel[11]+","+c.playerXP[11]+","+c.playerLevel[12]+","+c.playerXP[12]+","+c.playerLevel[13]+","+c.playerXP[13]+","+c.playerLevel[14]+","+c.playerXP[14]+","+c.playerLevel[15]+","+c.playerXP[15]+","+c.playerLevel[16]+","+c.playerXP[16]+","+c.playerLevel[17]+","+c.playerXP[17]+","+c.playerLevel[18]+","+c.playerXP[18]+","+c.playerLevel[19]+","+c.playerXP[19]+","+c.playerLevel[20]+","+c.playerXP[20]+");";
    String insQuery2 = "INSERT INTO `skillsoverall` (`playerName`,`lvl`,`xp`) VALUES ('"+c.playerName+"',"+totallevell+","+totallvlexp+");";
    String insQuery3 = "INSERT INTO `playerrights` (`playerName`,`rank`) VALUES ('"+c.playerName+"',"+c.playerRights+");";
    String[] delQueries = {delQuery1, delQuery2, delQuery3};
    String[] insQueries = {insQuery1, insQuery2, insQuery3};    

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        try(Connection conX = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/highscores","root","root")) {
            try(Statement stmtX = conX.createStatement()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < delQueries.length; i++)
                {
                    stmtX.executeUpdate(delQueries[i]);
                    stmtX.executeUpdate(insQueries[i]);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}       

}
```

Using this code how could I make it faster? If I used UPDATE instead would it make it faster? If it would please show me how to do that with the code I provided. I'm not very good with SQL, again just helping out a friend.

Comment: What do the indices look like? You probably could speed things up if you indexed the `playerName` column.

Comment: You want to see the table? Not sure what your asking. @JosepValls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ways to improve this:

- Use `UPDATE` statement and use the value of the primary key in the `WHERE` clause. This is in case you know the id. If you don't know it, then
- Use `UPDATE` statement properly. Add a proper index on the columns you will use for the `WHERE` clause, in case is a single column and it's not the primary key and this statement may be executed several times.
- Update the relevant columns, not all the columns (unless you are updating all the values for that row, which is something odd but not impossible).
- Since you want/need to update everything or nothing, then you should use a transaction. You can start a transaction by using `Connection#setAutoCommit(false);` and close it by using `Connection#commit`. In case of errors, use `Connection#rollback()` and none of the operations will affect the database.
- **Stop using `Statement` so naively**. If your queries need to be parameterized, then use `PreparedStatement` instead.

In your database, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE skills ADD INDEX idx_playerName (playerName);
```

Here's part of your Java code updated using the statements above:

```
public boolean saveHighScore(Client c) throws SQLException {
    long totallvlexp = (long) (c.playerXP[0]) + (c.playerXP[1]) + (c.playerXP[2]) + (c.playerXP[3]) + (c.playerXP[4]) + (c.playerXP[5]) + (c.playerXP[6]) + (c.playerXP[7]) + (c.playerXP[8]) + (c.playerXP[9]) + (c.playerXP[10]) + (c.playerXP[11]) + (c.playerXP[12]) + (c.playerXP[13]) + (c.playerXP[14]) + (c.playerXP[15]) + (c.playerXP[16]) + (c.playerXP[17]) + (c.playerXP[18]) + (c.playerXP[19]) + (c.playerXP[20]); 
    int totallevell = (int) (c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[0]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[1]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[2]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[3]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[4]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[5]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[6]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[7]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[8]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[9]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[10]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[11]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[12]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[13]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[14]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[15]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[16]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[17]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[18]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[19]) + c.getLevelForXP(c.playerXP[20]));
    boolean result = true;
    String updateSkillsSql = "UPDATE skills"
        + " SET `Attacklvl`=?,"
        + " `Attackxp`=?,"
        + " `Defencelvl`=?,"
        + " `Defencexp`=?,"
        + " `Strengthlvl`=?,"
        + " `Strengthxp`=?,"
        + " `Hitpointslvl`=?,"
        + " `Hitpointsxp`=?,"
        + " `Rangelvl`=?,"
        + " `Rangexp`=?,"
        + " `Prayerlvl`=?,"
        + " `Prayerxp`=?,"
        + " `Magiclvl`=?,"
        + " `Magicxp`=?,"
        + " `Cookinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Cookingxp`=?,"
        + " `Woodcuttinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Woodcuttingxp`=?,"
        + " `Fletchinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Fletchingxp`=?,"
        + " `Fishinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Fishingxp`=?,"
        + " `Firemakinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Firemakingxp`=?,"
        + " `Craftinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Craftingxp`=?,"
        + " `Smithinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Smithingxp`=?,"
        + " `Mininglvl`=?,"
        + " `Miningxp`=?,"
        + " `Herblorelvl`=?,"
        + " `Herblorexp`=?,"
        + " `Agilitylvl`=?,"
        + " `Agilityxp`=?,"
        + " `Thievinglvl`=?,"
        + " `Thievingxp`=?,"
        + " `Slayerlvl`=?,"
        + " `Slayerxp`=?,"
        + " `Farminglvl`=?,"
        + " `Farmingxp`=?,"
        + " `Runecraftlvl`=?,"
        + " `Runecraftxp`=?"
        + " WHERE playerName = ?";
    //do similar for the other queries...

    //not needed since JDBC 4, noted since you're using Java 7
    //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/highscores","root","root")) {
        //when storing multiple data, it's better to use a transaction
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        try(PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(updateSkillsSql);
            //declare the other PreparedStatements for each update sql statement here...
            ) {
            //do something like this for every PreparedStatement
            setParameters(pstmt,
                c.playerLevel[0], c.playerXP[0],
                c.playerLevel[1], c.playerXP[1],
                c.playerLevel[2], c.playerXP[2],
                c.playerLevel[3], c.playerXP[3],
                c.playerLevel[4], c.playerXP[4],
                c.playerLevel[5], c.playerXP[5],
                c.playerLevel[6], c.playerXP[6],
                c.playerLevel[7], c.playerXP[7],
                c.playerLevel[8], c.playerXP[8],
                c.playerLevel[9], c.playerXP[9],
                c.playerLevel[10], c.playerXP[10],
                c.playerLevel[11], c.playerXP[11],
                c.playerLevel[12], c.playerXP[12],
                c.playerLevel[13], c.playerXP[13],
                c.playerLevel[14], c.playerXP[14],
                c.playerLevel[15], c.playerXP[15],
                c.playerLevel[16], c.playerXP[16],
                c.playerLevel[17], c.playerXP[17],
                c.playerLevel[18], c.playerXP[18],
                c.playerLevel[19], c.playerXP[19],
                c.playerLevel[20], c.playerXP[20],
                c.playerName);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("There's a problem when saving the data of  player %s.", c.playerName));
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            con.rollback();
            result = false;
        }
        if (result) {
            con.commit();
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(String.format("There's a problem when saving the data of  player %s.", c.playerName));
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

//created method to add parameters despite its type    
private void setParameters(PreparedStatement pstmt, Object ... args) {
    int i = 1;
    for (Object arg : args) {
        pstmt.setObject(i++, arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could do that with the code I provided that would be very helpful. I'm not good with SQL i'm just using it for a one time thing for my friend. It's for an automatic system in a game you have skills with levels and experience and upon logout it saves your scores to the table along with hundreds of people ranking them accordingly.

Comment: Had to upvote this - pretty much same as what I said, but you type faster.

Comment: yours could be better if you showed using it in my code @LDMJoe

Comment: @Joliquine4 I don't really care if you're new to sql or think you will use it once in your life, since this site is for any future reader (and that may include us in a future time). I've updated part of your code using the advices I give in the answer, I didn't do for all the queries since it's very long.

Comment: i'm getting an error because it can't find what "setParameter" is what can I do? @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Code updated. It's `setObject`, not `setParameter`, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest cost in either your `DELETE` / `INSERT` approach or an `UPDATE` approach is probably your `WHERE` clause.

Doing the `UPDATE` or `DELETE` with a `WHERE` pointing at `playerName = 'FriendlyNameOfPlayer'` is brutal.  You could make it a little better if you created an index on that field.

You'd create the index with something along the lines of...

```
CREATE INDEX playerName_ix ON skills (playerName)
CREATE INDEX playerName_ix ON skillsoverall (playerName)
```

Read more on some additional options that may be relevant on a case by case basis [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

A better practice would be to target the rows by their `PK` (maybe an auto-incrementing integer?).  Ideally, the schema behind this would be a table called `Player_Master` with an autoincrementing integer as the `PK`, then the friendly name of the player stored in another column.  Tables like those referenced in your code snippit should be storing the PK values from `Player_Master` (instead of the friendly name), which would be `FK`'s.  Your `DELETE` statement would instead look like...

```
DELETE FROM `skills` WHERE skills.playerID = 37
```

Redoing the schema would be the "correct" way to do it, but I get that every project may not have the time or resources required for a total teardown / redo.  If your buddy is saying "can you make this faster?", you could do the index and walk away.  If the question were "how do I do this right?", I'd start the clock on billable hours, because from the small glimpse into the code and schema provided, it's not a quick fix.

I'll also wristslap you for calling raw executes of cobbled together TSQL statements.  There are better ways to do this.

Comment: Could you show me this in the code I provided? I'm not good with SQL I'm just using it for one thing to help my buddy out.